# Is is possible to view all activities in calendar widget?

Tags: activities, calendar, widget

I am part of a small company that uses CiviCRM for project management. Until now we have been using Google Calendar where all the managers and members of the company could see everyone's calendar.

Is there any way we can do this using the CiviCRM calendar widget? The only way I have found is to assign the activities created to everyone so that everyone can see them, but this does not make sense if not all managers/members participate in that activity.

This is a problem as sometimes an administrator assigns me tasks in schedules that are already occupied by activities added by me and assigned to me because that administrator cannot see my activitities in his/her calendar widget.

I hope someone can help me (us)!

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like some good answers below - also note, if using Drupal you could build a View to do this

Answer (score 2):

There is a `CiviCRM: view all activities` permission that would allow everyone to see the activities even though they are not tagged also there is [Activity Type ACL](https://civicrm.org/extensions/activity-type-acl) extension that will allow specific activity type to be seen by all.

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep, but nothing works. I've checked all the boxes for the role Editor but this role still cannot see all activities in the calendar widget.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I installed the extension [Contact Calendar](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-calendar) and added all members to the activities as a target contact, leaving the responsible/s as the assignee of the activity.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if the current calendar display does not meet your needs, there is a new extension for [SearchKit Calendar Displays](https://lab.civicrm.org/ayduns/calendarskdisplay), currently under development. Everyone is encouraged to try it out and leave feedback or submit improvements for this new extension.

Comment: Thanks, but the instructions are unclear on how to proceed after the installation. Besides, I can find any option related to this plugin in the CiviCRM admin pages nor menus.

Comment: After installation you use searchKit as normal, but now there is a new type of display available (in addition to Table, List, Grid, etc)